# QueryDSL Cases Expression not pulling data

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm working to implement a Native query in QueryDSL and I'm getting a weird scenario where a value in a Case statement doesn't get saved into my Projected Java object. The `source_field_amount` in the `THEN` always comes back as 0.

I have a query like:

```
SELECT 
    (
        CASE WHEN (field_A = 'N' OR field_A IS NULL)
        THEN source_field_amount
        ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS targetFieldA,
    (
        CASE WHEN (field_B = 'Y')
        THEN source_field_amount 
        ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS targetFieldB,
FROM table
WHERE <some_condition>
```

I wrote that up in QueryDSL like this (it does a lot more but I'm simplifying).

```
private final SQLQueryFactory queryFactory;

public DataResponse testMethod() {
    return queryFactory.select(Projections.bean(DataResponse.class, Expressions.cases()
                        .when(fieldA.eq("N").or(fieldA.isNull()))
                        .then(table.sourceFieldAmount)
                        .otherwise(BigDecimal.ZERO)
                        .as("targetFieldA"),
                Expressions.cases()
                        .when(fieldA.eq("Y"))
                        .then(table.sourceFieldAmount)
                        .otherwise(BigDecimal.ZERO)
                        .as("targetFieldB"),
                        table.sourceFieldAmount))
                .distinct()
                .from(table)
                .fetchOne();
}
```

```
@Data
public DataResponse {
    private BigDecimal targetFieldA;
    private BigDecimal targetFieldB;
    private BigDecimal sourceFieldAmount;
}
```

When I hit this endpoint, I get 0 for both targetFieldA and targetFieldB. SourceFieldAmount here is for debugging and I get 0.76.

```
{
    "targetFieldA": 0,
    "targetFieldB": 0,
    "sourceFieldAmount": 0.76,
}
```

I know that it's not always hitting that `else` condition as I've changed `BigDecimal.ZERO` to `BigDecimal.TEN` and it still prints 0.

Any idea what the problem is? I do have some case/when/then statements working fine in my code. I believe this used to work when I was using JPAExpressions, but I had to switch to the QueryDSL SQLQuery because of using a subQuery which isn't supported in JPAQuery from what I found.

I know I can just return the `sourceFieldAmount` and set the variables myself, but this was working well and cleaner to compare a provided Native Query with my QueryDSL, and I'm also trying to understand why it doesn't work. And I'm concerned I need to review the rest of my code and make sure none of these are broken elsewhere.

Comment: I never got an answer to why it's happening. I think it was working fine with JPA but with the SQL query from QueryDSL it didn't. It seems to work fine with constants in the .then() clause, but not pulled from a value in the database. I ended up having to just return all the values and do the assignments in pure Java code vs using the QueryDSL libraries.